# Отправка изображений в email

Tags: html

Подскажите, как отправить HTML код, чтобы приходила картинка. Код в браузере нормально открывается, а по почте не хочет картинку показывать.

Comment: Каким образом вы отправляете? Где находится картинка, которую вы отправляете? Как вы ссылаетесь на неё? Больше деталей.

Comment: напишите исходный код.


Answer (score 0, accepted):

<body background="картинка">
Сюда текст.
</body>
картинку куда нибудь на хостинг.

Comment: Вот есть например определённый код HTML, пускай реклама - да, в браузере открывается - всё отлично, ОК. Как отправить этот код, чтобы открылась реклама в виде картинки, а не код?? Как необходимо вставить код в письмо? Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: В настройках клиента укажите, что посылаете html. Это уже от сервиса зависит, я вообще через еундерберд сижу. И не забудьте, клиентский софт/или, если смотрят через сайт, может не поддерживать html, или еще как вариант он может быть отключен у конкретного пользователя.
То есть человек получит письмо корректно, html, но увидит исходный код. Потому что почта по умолчанию - текст(ну как пример).